# Hide/Show Form elements in Alfresco share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am still fairly new to Alfresco and thought I was trying to do something common, but I can't figure out how to do it.  My basic question: is there a simple (built-in) way of hiding or showing one field based on the value of another?

*Details*:

I would like to be able to do something like this in my share-config.xml file:

```
<field id="a:thisField" label="This Field Label">
    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/hide.ftl">
        <control-param name="property">a:myCheckboxField</control-param>
    </control>
</field>
```

This would show or hide the entire 'thisField' whenever a checkbox was checked or unchecked.  Of course, there is no 'hide.ftl'!   From what I have read, I gather I could write something like that to do what I want, but isn't this really so basic that it should be supported somehow?  [Besides, I don't haven't had to do anything like that yet, so it would be all new.] If there is an easy way, I couldn't find it and would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

There is no special support to act on one field depending on the value of another.

I guess the easiest thing to do would be to come up with a custom `two-in-one.ftl` housing both fields.